# Filtering posts by ACF filed using WP Rest API

Tags: rest-api

I would like to hit the REST Api of WordPress to receive in response posts that met a specific condition defined in the ACF field. I have tried building the request in several ways, but each time it gets all post. Ultimately, I would like to receive data by hitting an endpoint like this:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?shared=true
```

I tried to add something like this in functions.php but unfortunately it does not solve my problem, because I still receive all the posts.

```
function my_add_meta_vars ($current_vars) {
    $current_vars = array_merge ($current_vars, array ('meta_key', 'meta_value'));
    return $current_vars;
}
add_filter ('rest_query_vars', 'my_add_meta_vars');

add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args) {

    $args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'shared',
        'value' => esc_sql( $_GET['shared'] ),
        )
    );

    //echo $args['meta_query'][0]['value'];
    //print_r($args);

    if (!empty($args['meta_query'][0]['value'])) {
        return $args;       
    }
```

} );

I tried to get it this way

```
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?shared=true
```

In such:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[shared]=true
```

I would be very grateful for any advice